# HTTPS request from Android mobile gets failure from 3G and 4G network but works fine in 2G network

Tags: ssl, 3g, handshake, sslhandshakeexception, 4g

We are trying to make a https request from Android mobile application using volley library, but we are getting the following error com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xdf35c180: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error error:100c50e3:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:SSL_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:756 0xe8b837d7:0x00000000)

This issue pertains only in the networks like 3G and 4G, but working fine with other networks like 2G.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late. But I had the same problem. For me it was due to 1&1 had randomly system assigned IP6 addresses to all my domains,even when A record pointed outside their network. This meant anything attempting IP6 would now try because there was an IP6 address. My NGINX config was not setup for this and failed. I had to remove the IP6addresses in my control panel for 1&1